# I have to generate the date alone from the string mentioned below as it will change everyday in hive query

Tags: hive

How do I generate **'19920121**' using `substr` or `regexp_extract` function in hive from the following string as the file name will be changing with the date on daily basis?

> hdfs://abcdef001.abc.com:8020/hadoop/dev/ops360/etl/raw/eods/datalak_big_driver/input/datalak_big_driver_19920121.dat

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the date part is at the end of the file. The below one worked. Try it out

```
select regexp_extract('hdfs://abcdef001.abc.com:8020/hadoop/dev/ops360/etl/raw/eods/datalak_big_driver/input/datalak_big_driver_19920121.dat',"(\\d+)\.dat", 1);

+-----------+--+
|    _c0    |
+-----------+--+
| 19920121  |
+-----------+--+
```